# Layout tips for GND?

Tags: pcb, kicad

Is it OK to not connect the GND pins and at the end I fill the zone with copper pour?

When I run the DRC in KiCad everything looks good (all pads are connected.)

Comment: It doesn't matter what order you add elements to your design, as long as everything is right when you generate the CAM files. You might find that doing things in a certain order makes things easier for the kind of designs you do, but that won't have any effect on the final product.

Comment: Yes, you can just do a ground pour without routing ground. Watch for islands or isolated signals which ERC should catch. There are times this isn't explicitly true but for basic boards it should be ok.